# Viewing active users in my ASP.NET web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

I store registered users to database db_register.
I want to store each user's id to an array the time they log in.
How can I store each user id to an array?

Comment: please show some source... what have you tried ? what doesn't work ? any error messages/exceptions ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using FormsAuthentication,

1. You will get all users from `Membership.GetAllUsers();`.
2. It returns a `MembershipUserCollection`.
3. Enumerate through `MembershipUser` on that collection.
4. You will see a boolean property called `MembershipUser.IsOnline`

Populate that collection in a GridView and you can see all Users who are online.

Comment: Right, but are you saying this doesn't work with Windows or Custom auth?

Comment: @ Henk Holterman: I fear that the OP might have only loginid and password for each users

Answer (score 0):

There is a multitude of ways that you could achieve this and I think you need to supply more detaisl about how you're controlling logins etc.

If you're not using FormsAuthentication and you don't want to persist the logged on user state to the DB then I'd say your best bet would be to have a collection/list of logged on users in your Application state. So as a user logs on, you add them to the list. Something like:

```
(List<string>)(Application["loggedUsers"]).Add(loggedonusername);
```

Then, on a seprate page you could bind a grid/repeater etc. to Application["loggedUsers"].

When a user logs out or their session ends, you remove the entry from the application state.

Alternatively if you have access to modifying your DB, you could add a field to the User table (if you have one) that denotes whether or not the user is logged on - this would replace storing the users in Application state.

Comment: No sure I'm following your question Roshan

Comment: Can you maybe supply some code showing what you're doing s far?

Comment: plz help...i store registered users to database db_register    
i want to store each users id to an arry the time they login    
how can i store each user id to an arry